# Keycloak identity broker european special characters in name replaced by?

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, redhat

I have a Keycloak v7.4.4 running and have setup an OIDC identity provider (signicat). Everything but getting the name works as expected.

The issue is that if the name of the logged in user contains an european special characters such as "ø" it is replaced by "?".

Does anyone have had a similar issue and maybe fixed it somehow?

Comment: exactly where is the name wrong? In Keycloak or in your own application? Typically it is because your web application is using the wrong encoding standard (utf8...)

Comment: It is inside keycloak..

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue with certain characters. They seem to get stored as "replacement characters" in the database (Postgres, UTF8 encoding everywhere), like:

"Ł" becomes �� or U+FFFD U+FFFD, or as hex: EF BF BD EF BF BD.

The original data comes from Azure AD which works as the identity provider, but somehow inside Keycloak the unicode gets mangled. This is mostly an inconvenience for us, as it only affects the display name so far, but a very annoying one...

Edit: Keycloak is the Bitnami packaged version (13.0.1) and Postgres AWS managed RDS instance (13.2)

Edit 2: The problem in my case was the Bitnami packaged Keycloak. Switching to [jboss/keycloak](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak) made everything work as expected.

Comment: oh, and everything works just fine if the data is corrected manually in the database, so the problem is with storing the user